# Changing powers to sums in a simple system of equations

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, systems-of-equations, extremal-combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Let's say we have the system of $l$ equations below:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a_{11}^{a_{12}}=a_{13} \\ 
a_{21}^{a_{22}}=a_{23} \\ 
\ldots \\
a_{l1}^{a_{l2}}=a_{l3} \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Here, every $a_{ij}$ is actually a variable chosen from a set of variables $V_{I}=\{b_1 , b_2 , \ldots b_n\}$, such that the three corresponding variables(the b's) in each equation are distinct and each $b_i$ occurs in the system. Denote this system with I and assume that there exists a set of n different integers(one for each $b_i$) which is a solution.

Is it always true that the same system(but with powers changed to additions everywhere) denoted with II:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a_{11} + a_{12}=a_{13} \\ 
a_{21} + a_{22}=a_{23} \\ 
\ldots \\
a_{l1} + a_{l2}=a_{l3} \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

must also have a solution - a set of n distinct integers? Here, each $a_{ij}$ refers to the same variable from the set V as in system I. [The example in the comment should clarify the set up]

Note 1: The answer seems to be 'YES', since taking powers is much more complicated than doing additions). How can we prove it?

Note 2: We would have a trivial counterexample if we include the two equations $x^y =p$ and $y^x = q$ in I. Thus we must also add the constraint $\{a_{i1},a_{i2}\}\neq \{a_{j1},a_{j2}\}$, for all $i\neq j$.

Comment: an eventual counterexample could be related to the non-commutativity of taking powers.

Comment: For example, let I be the system:
$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x^{y}=z \\ 
y^{p}=q \\ 
x^{z}=q \\ 
\end{array}
\right. $$
which means that $V=\{x,y,z,p,q\}$. There exist solutions of distinct integers, e.g. $x=3$, $y=3^3$, $z=3^8$, $p=3^{3^{3}}$, $q=3^{3^{3^{3}}}$. The corresponding system II:

$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x+y=z \\ 
y+p=q \\ 
x+z=q \\ 
\end{array}
\right. $$
also has a solution of distinct integers. For instance, $x=2$, $y=1$, $z=3$, $p=4$, $q=5$.
My question is -is this true for all systems?

Answer (score 1):

Since the goalposts keep moving, I find myself here again.  And because I don't ever want to have to come back, rather than spending time answering the question you are currently asking, I will reformulate your current question and ask you whether it captures what you actually mean to ask.

Let $I_\ell$ and $II_\ell$ be the two frames you specify, each containing $\ell$ equation.  (I note that you do not require equations to be distinct.  Requiring or not requiring distinctness does not change what follows.)

Let $R$ be the set of "numbers".  Let $\mathscr{P}$ denote the powerset function and let $\phi$ be the (family of) forgetful functor(-s) $f:R^n \rightarrow \mathscr{P}(R): (r_1, r_2, \dots, r_n) \mapsto \{r_1, r_2, \dots, r_n\}$.  (Note that $\phi$ forgets duplicates in the $n$-vector.)  Define a solution pool, $C_k$, to be an element of $R^k$ where $|\phi(C_k)| = k$.

Define the cardinality spectrum of a frame $F$, containing the variables $(a_{ij} \mid 1 \leq i \leq \ell, j \in \{1,2,3\})$ to be the set of $k$ such that there exists a solution pool $C_k$ where $F$ has a solution with $a_{ij} \in C_k$ for $1 \leq i \leq \ell, j \in \{1,2,3\}$.

The Question asks:  Is the cardinality spectrum of $I_\ell$ always a subset of the cardinality spectrum of $II_\ell$.

Does this capture what you actually want to know?

### Prior Answer

Let $a_{i1} = a_{i3} = i$ and $a_{i2} = 1$.  Then $S_I = [1,l] \subset \Bbb{Z}$.  The $i^\text{th}$ equation in II requires $\{i,1,i+1\}$ which are all in $S_I$ except for the $l^\text{th}$, which requires the new integer $l+1 \not \in S_I$.  Consequently, with this choice of I, $S_{II} = [1,l+1]$ has larger cardinality than $S_I$.

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstanding, but the numbers in the ith equation in the system II are not necessary the same as those in the ith equation of I. I made some changes to make it more clear.

Comment: @Euler_rand : I understood this.  This example has $|S_I|+1 = |S_{II}|$.  The interesting challenge from (scratch work) random examples was to make the two sets close to the same size.  Making them wildly different sizes was too easy.

Comment: my bad, again. I forgot to mention that the three numbers in each equation for the two systems are not equal to each other(i.e. $a_{i1}=a_{i3}$ is not addmiissible).

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand your reformulation, but I rewrote my question entirely and I am pretty sure the problem will be clear now. Thanks for writing back.